# Comparing Multiple Properties in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

What is the best way/tool to get a snapshot of stats across multiple websites in GA?

I have 20 or so related websites, and need to be able to compare unique visitors / total visitors etc at a glance.

I suspect I am looking for one of these Apps: http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/ but not sure which would best suit that purpose.

Comment: I have developed [http://www.embeddedanalytics.com](http://embeddedanalytics.com).  We are listed on that page.  You certainly could create widgets for each of your profiles and place them on a single page to see a snapshot.  We also have a way so that you could define one chart/object and script in a google analytics profile.

Comment: That's pretty cool, and I can see using it in another another project. I guess it's limited by what you have already defined though right? I tried another tool which only had about 20 defined widgets which really wasn't flexible enough. (I want to compare 6 custom GA dashboards with 5-12 widgets across ~20 profiles), including integrated events/goals etc and filter excludes/includes.